# Special characters in Salt state

Tags: yaml, salt-stack

I am using Salt and I have to append some text to a file,after some research I found that you can achieve that by using the `file.append` module.

I am getting an error about adding something like `[text]` in the file:

```
failed: could not found expected ':';at line x
```

The state is:

```
file.append:
  - text: |
    blah blah blah
    [SSL]    <====================== Here is where it complains
    blah blah
```

Should I try to escape  the `[` character using the `\` before or how am I able to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your indentation. A mapping value must be indented more than its key:

```yaml
file.append:
  - text: |
      blah blah blah
      [SSL]
      blah blah
```

Comment: Thanks,You are right on this:I found a different solution on this: using `-` for each line of text which seems to work just as well